# Finding files over a range of time

Tags: intellij-idea, find, repository, gitlab

Is it possible to find how many new files have been created over a given time period, via IntelliJ or Gitlab?  My team is interested in seeing how many new automation feature files we've created (via Cucumber) over a quarter span.  Not sure how to best do that.

Answer (score 0):

I may have answered this myself, though it seems a little hacky.  But it works!  What I did was create a local branch then searched for the files using the Windows search tool, via this query in the local repo folder:

```
type:.feature datecreated:‎1/‎1/‎2018 .. 4/11/2018
```

There may yet be a much better answer but this got me the data I was after.

Comment: you can do this query in intelliJ too. Just use the version control integration and tag the two commits you want to compare or branches like you already created.